# MySQL Return NULL on Failed JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have two MySql Tables: `contracts` and `customers`. Customers may have contracts linked to them. Some contracts exist without customers, and some customers have no contracts. I need to query for all customers and contracts, and where possible, join them in the same row. In rows where no contract or customer are found, I would like to simply place `NULL`.

As it stands, I am only returning rows where both are present. I realize that's what a join is for, but I'm not sure how to simply return everything. Specifying no `JOIN` clause returns each result multiple times, which also won't do.

Here's the insufficient SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT cu.ID, cu.`Name`, cu.Contract, co.ID, co.`Type`
FROM test.customers cu
INNER JOIN test.contracts co ON co.ID = cu.Contract;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for a `full outer join` which MySQL does not support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are interested in is called a "left join".

```
SELECT cu.ID, cu.`Name`, cu.Contract, co.ID, co.`Type`
FROM test.customers cu
LEFT JOIN test.contracts co ON co.ID = cu.Contract;
```

This will return nulls for the contracts where there are no matches.

However, that will not find instances of "no customers" as well.

The solution is to add a second query and union that in as well.

```
UNION 
SELECT cu.ID, cu.`Name`, cu.Contract, co.ID, co.`Type`
FROM test.contracts co
LEFT JOIN test.customers cu ON co.ID = cu.Contract
WHERE cu.ID is null;
```